# Motivation behind Lagrangian duality

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

As the title states, what is the motivation behind the Lagrangian duality in integer programming? I tried looking up online references including the post: [BigPicture Lagrangian, KKT, Duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573505/bigpicture-lagrangian-kkt-duality), and also $\textbf{Wolsey's}$ $\textit{Integer}$ $\textit{Programming}$ but I can't picture the concepts intuitively (especially certain variables - such as the penalty term $u(d-Dx)$ are introduced). Some insight will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for maybe a sort of "application" of duality, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method. So if our primal problem doesn't have inner products, we can try to see if the dual problem contains inner products in its terms and then apply the kernel trick.

Comment: I've not learnt that yet and it will probably take quite some time for that, but it does look interesting! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Did you learn Lagrange Duality as part of a Machine Learning class?

Comment: @learning No, its solely based on integer programming.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if you'll be taught the kernel method there, but it's nice to know!

Comment: what is you perspective? Wolsey’s book is enough clear about duality in Integer Programming

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra I apologize if I am unclear about this, but to be precise, I am unable to comprehend the introduction of certain terms in Wolsey's, such as the penalty term $u(d-Dx)$, and also why dropping constraints in Lagrangian relaxation is useful in relation to Lagrangian duality. I shall make the appropriate edits in my question.

Comment: May be this paper could help you [link](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~benkoczi/OR/read/lagrange-relax-introduct-fisher85.pdf)

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra That's a great paper! It helped me get a bigger picture, but also led me to 2 soft questions: on page 11, why does dualizing constraint $(2)$ lead to the new objective function $Z_p(u)$? Also, on page 12, why can we set a variable to $0$ when its objective coefficient is not positive?

Comment: @Stoner Happy for that! As for your “soft” questions, keep in mind that: 1) the optimal value of  the Lagrangian function $Z_{LR}(x,u)=cx+u(b-Ax)$  depends on $u$; therefore we can define this dependency as a function, the Lagrangian Dual function, $Z_D(u)=\max Z_{LR}(x,u)$; 2) the Lagrangian problem is a maximisation problem with binary variables; therefore if the lagrangian cost of a variable is negative, for a given set of multipliers, then that variable will take the null value whenever it is feasible.

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra Thank you for the clarification. It really helped clarify my doubts! :)